# Weighting on position within a range of numbers

Tags: numerical-methods, matrix-rank

Firstly, hello all. I'm normally to be found on StackOverflow but felt that this forum was more appropriate for my question. Count this is a coffee break teaser, rather than a fully challenging maths problem and have fun with it!

Hopefully I can explain this clearly.

**The problem**

I am trying to establish a weighting for the *position* of a number within a variable range of elements. The actual element numbers don't matter themeselves, purely their place in the order that they are presented. for example, given the range.

`1, 9, 2, 4`

the number `9` in simple terms would have a weighting of `0.5` due to my very simple calculation of `position/number of items`. This of course works great if all my ranges are only comprised 4 items. Things get tricky when for example, I want to derive a weighting for the next range of elements:

`1, 46, 2, 9, 23, 4, 5, 56`

In this example, the number `9` STILL has a weighting of `0.5` as it conforms to the same equation. What I'd like to achieve is a weighting that signifies the fact that the length of the range is greater and therefore being in the middle (or any other arbitary position) has a radically different index due to the range length etc.

**The reason**

The rationale behind this is that I'd like to determine an index value for a horse in a race based on its position in a given bookies odds ranking. Therefore, in a field of 20 runners, the horse at position 10 would in theory have the `0.5` index value. However, in a field of 4 runners, the horse ranked #2 (index 0.5) has a far greater chance of winning than the 10th runner of 20. Applying a simple 1 in 20 chance for each runner won't cut it as the ranking is derived from form factors and other shenanigans.

Is there a simple way to represent this requirement? (btw - please feel free to edit the tags, I wasn't 100% certain where my question lay)